# DocuSign API: Can I get a nicely formatted Envelope Audit Results?

Tags: c#, .net, docusignapi

Using the DocuSign API SDK, C#.

I have a notification processor that handles the Connect notifications.  When we get one for an envelope Completed (or Voided), that's when we grab any associated documents plus the Certificate of Completion.  Well, the folks over in the Compliance department saw the Envelope History on the DocuSign website and would like to have that, too -- saved as a "document" in the database. (It has a little more detail than the Certificate.)

Here's what I'm using to get the envelope audit events:

```
EnvelopeAuditEventResponse auditReponse = await envelopesApi.ListAuditEventsAsync(Account.AccountId, envelopeId);
```

That works fine, but the results are in raw form -- I can understand them, but the Compliance folks cannot.

Has anyone been successful in formatting the EnvelopeAuditEventResponse instance into something a business person (not a developer) can read?  PDF would be great, but I'd take HTML or even formatted text.

If you have any questions, please let me know.

thanks,
randy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Envelopes:listAuditEvents](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents) returns an array of name/value pairs.

I'd suggest just printing them out, in order (it's an array). If the `errorDetails` or `originalValue` attributes have values, include them in the output line for that item.

Together, the audit events and certificate of completion provide a complete picture of the transaction.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  As I was thinking about how to put this together in some sort of "report", I realized the business types are gurus at doing reports as long as they have the data.  Then why not just write all the audit events to the database (I'm already logging other notifications from DocuSign in this app)?  Then they can develop whatever report suits their needs.  Seems like a win-win all around.

Comment: Good idea. I'd include a sort column based on the item's index within the result array. Thank you for the check.